# Clone record but update value prior to cloning

Tags: apex

I originally was Cloning a record and the code below works well but need to be able to update a couple fields prior to the new record being created. I need to append the Date the Name field and populate a lookup with the Parent id.  This is a proposal process and I am trying to keep track of the original and all new proposals.  All Cloned records need to look up to the Original Proposed record.  Can the existing code be modified to accommodate this?

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static String cloneAnySobjet(String recordId){
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    String objectAPIName = '';
    String keyPrefix = recordId.substring(0,3);
    for( Schema.SObjectType obj : schemaMap.Values() ){
        String prefix = obj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
        if(prefix == keyPrefix){
            objectAPIName = 'Proposal__c';
            break;
        }
    }
    Set <String> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectAPIName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
    String soqlQuery = 'SELECT ' ; 
    for (String s :fieldMap ){
        system.debug('fields ' + s);
        if(schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectAPIName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(s).getDescribe().isAccessible()){
            soqlQuery +=  + s+',';
        }
    }

    soqlQuery =  soqlQuery.removeEnd(',');
    system.debug('soqlQuery ' + soqlQuery);
    system.debug('recordId ' + recordId);
    soqlQuery += ' FROM ' +objectAPIName +' WHERE ID = \'' + recordId +'\'' ;

    SObject record = Database.query(soqlQuery);
    system.debug('record ' + record);
    SObject clondedParentRecordID= record.clone(false, false, false, false);
    try{
        insert clondedParentRecordID ;
        return clondedParentRecordID.id ;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return '' ;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at this line:

```
SObject clondedParentRecordID= record.clone(false, false, false, false);
```

you could do:

```
clonedParentRecordID.put('Name',clonedParentRecordId.get('Name')+Date.today());
```

and do the same for other fields using the [get and put methods on sobject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

*N.B. I wouldn't name the variable `clonedRecordObjectId` by the way as it is a record, not an Id,
better would be: `clonedRecordObject` or even better `clonedSObject`*

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So I add your suggestion under the `SObject clondedParentRecordID= record.clone(false, false, false, false);`  I am receiving an error 'Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments'. Is this do to how the Name and Date value are being appended together?

Comment: That's what it was: `clondedParentRecordID.put('Name',clondedParentRecordID.get('Name') + ' '+ Date.today());`